# Can't get correct price with getPrice

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to add schema / microdata to my website. I have added the below code, but when I test the site with Googles tool I get the wrong price. If a product is set to 99,00 - Google reads it as 9900. For some unknown reason,  getPrice reads the price as 9900 from my magento shop. If I change price to 99,12 - getPrice reads 9912

```
    <!-- MICRODATA -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>" />
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo $currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>">
    <?php 
    $specialPrice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
    $normalPrice = $_product->getPrice();
    if ($normalPrice != $specialPrice){
    ?>
      <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice()))); ?>">
     <?php
    }else{
    ?>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice()))); ?>">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    $microdata_stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getIsInStock();
    if ($microdata_stock >= 1){
      $microdata_stock_msg = 'In Stock';
    }else{
      $microdata_stock_msg = 'Out of Stock';
    }
    ?>
    <meta itemprop="availability" content="<?php echo $microdata_stock_msg; ?>">
    <meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition" />
  </div>
</div>
<!-- MICRODATA -->
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code. Its work for my all websites

```
currency($_product->getFinalPrice());?>
```

Please  check this link. Hope it will help you :)
https://paulnrogers.com/guide-to-adding-rich-snippets-in-magento/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am already using that code to getPrice and getFinalPrice. In frontend the price shows 99,00 - In backend it's 99.00 but getPrice is 9900. Tried the above link, but with same problem. Still not getting the right price from getPrice and getFinalPrice.

Comment: I am using a danish translated magento setup.

Comment: Can you please provide me link of page in which you are getting wrong price.

Answer (score 0):

Your Price micro data should be look like as given below.

```
<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span><span
          itemprop="price" content="1000.00">1,000.00</span>
```

As per [schema.org](http://schema.org/price) Use '.' (Unicode 'FULL STOP' (U+002E)) rather than ',' to indicate a decimal point. Avoid using these symbols as a readability separator.

Comment: Not sure what you mean and what to change in my code

Comment: Please compare your output with http://schema.org/price  . There is price text missing in   code

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '',str_replace(',','.',strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getFinalPrice())))); ?>">
```

With this I replace the "," with a "."